# How to test random API calls?

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests

How to test a API by random calls?

I could not find a tool for it (especially for Java in my case), so maybe someone knows one.

Background: A new API can be tested with Unit tests, e2e tests or tests based on realistic processes. But what I am missing is a test with random API calls to cover an unexpected order of calls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Executor Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) is what you're after:

> Depending on which concrete Executor class is being used, tasks may execute in a newly created thread, an existing task-execution thread, or the thread calling execute, and may execute sequentially or concurrently.

The collections described there are also useful. Take a look at how to do [Asynchronous Method Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html).